# Facing issues writing names in a csv file using panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I've written a scraper in python to parse different names from a webpage. As I'm very new to panda so can't understand how to write data in a csv file properly. The way I've written my script does scrape desired names but in case of writing to a csv file it only write the last name. Any help on this will be vastly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/596974-socket-error-10061-connection-refused').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
for name in soup.select(".smallfont a"):
    item = pd.DataFrame([name.text])[0]
    item.to_csv('file.csv')
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your question, but the problem is that you are overwriting the dataframe in the loop. In this way, just the last data in the list will be recorded on csv file.

Try this code:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/596974-socket-
error-10061-connection-refused').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
items_list = []
for name in soup.select(".smallfont a"):
    items_list.append(name.text)

item = pd.DataFrame(items_list)
item.to_csv('file.csv')
print(item)
```

Out put:

```
                                                   0
0  boost::asio (Permission denied, Connection ref...
1               Error Code 10061: Connection refused
2                    socket.error connection refused
3              Connection refused error from browser
4  connection refused when uploading a package to...
5                smtplib (111, 'Connection refused')
6  sending of mail (smtp) - connection refused - ...
7              socket object, connection refused ...
8                                 socket error 10061
```

Is this your intention?

Comment: Yep it is. Thanks Rafael Araújo.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need panda ?

```
with open('file.csv', 'w+') as f:
    for name in soup.select(".smallfont a"):
        item = name.decode_contents()
        f.write(item)
        print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks Loïc, for your answer. I actually know how to write in a csv file if it were not for panda. Thanks again.